# Can't access Webmin from browser - "Cron 15430088014649 missing any time spec"

Tags: server, debian, vps, webmin

Webmin has started, but I can't access it from the web. When I restart it, it throws the error I gave in the title. I've tracked the source of the error to this line of code:

https://github.com/webmin/webmin/blob/master/miniserv.pl#L5969

If I try to connect to any other port that is not Webmin's, the connection gets immediately rejected, but if I use Webmin's port, I wait and wait until it times out (in the browser, curl stays forever).

Does anybody have an idea of what I can do to fix this?

```
besto@host:~/tmp$ sudo /etc/init.d/webmin restart
Stopping Webmin server in /usr/share/webmin
Starting Webmin server in /usr/share/webmin
Cron 15430088014649 missing any time spec
besto@host:~/tmp$
```

Comment: I am getting the same notice (`Cron 154370519411408 missing any time spec`) but I am able to access it via the webinterface but I unable to login.

Comment: So the error is just a symptom. Sad. If you manage to find out the source, please come by and share it. I will do the same.

Comment: You should probably raise this in the webmin forum: https://sourceforge.net/p/webadmin/discussion/600155

Comment: I got this problem as well after manually changing the webmin port in /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf. I reverted that and then changed the port through the webmin interface itself. For some reason that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Webmin Github page](https://github.com/webmin/webmin/issues/994), the error has nothing to do with not being able to access Webmin.

Maybe you're missing the https://